# Image source not readable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload image from `base64` image in two version, one `250px` another `650px` with watermark and it give me back an error: **Image source not readable**

```
    $path = public_path().'/seller/uploads/'. $seller->id .'/'. $adsid;  
    $watermark = public_path().'/watermark.png';
    $Image = explode(";base64,", $img);
    $ImageName = $date;
    $ImageDecode = base64_decode($Image[1]);
    $thumb_name = $ImageName.'-thumb.jpg';
    $resize_name = $ImageName.'-resized.jpg';

Image::make($ImageDecode)->encode('jpg', 80)->orientate()->resize(250, null, function ($constraint) {
$constraint->aspectRatio();
})->save($path.'/'.$thumb_name);

Image::make($ImageDecode)->encode('jpg', 80)->orientate()->resize(650, null, function ($constraint) {
$constraint->aspectRatio();
})->insert($watermark, 'bottom-right', 10, 10)->save($path.'/'.$resize_name);
```

Error:

> exception: "Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException"
> file:
> "E:\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\AbstractDecoder.php"
> line: 351 message: "Image source not readable"

What I have missed?

```
xampp 
PHP Version 8.1.12
Laravel Framework 8.83.23
```

Comment: ``Image::make()`` accepts base64encoded string while you're passing decoded string which is why the source is not readable !! https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/make. Direcly pass the ``$img`` to the ``make`` method.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file folder names properly or not and also check the read permission for the folder you are trying to access through your code. Many time issue in such cases is the file/folder name

Answer (score -1):

Verify file paths: Double-check that the paths to the source image and watermark file are correct and accessible. Make sure that the **$img**, **$path**, and **$watermark** variables contain the correct paths to the respective files.

Handle file encoding: Verify that the base64 decoding of the image data **$ImageDecode** is successful. Ensure that the base64 string is valid and contains the correct image data.

```
    use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    
    try {
        $path = public_path('seller/uploads/'.$seller->id.'/'.$adsid);
        $watermark = public_path('watermark.png');
        $Image = explode(";base64,", $img);
        $ImageName = $date;
        $ImageDecode = base64_decode($Image[1]);
        $thumb_name = $ImageName.'-thumb.jpg';
        $resize_name = $ImageName.'-resized.jpg';
    
        // Create thumbnail image
        Image::make($ImageDecode)
            ->encode('jpg', 80)
            ->orientate()
            ->resize(250, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })
            ->save($path.'/'.$thumb_name);
    
        // Create resized image with watermark
        Image::make($ImageDecode)
            ->encode('jpg', 80)
            ->orientate()
            ->resize(650, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })
            ->insert($watermark, 'bottom-right', 10, 10)
            ->save($path.'/'.$resize_name);
    
        // Success message
        echo 'Image processed successfully!';
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Handle the exception
        echo 'Error: '.$e -> getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).